# how to avoid re-rendering when useEffect changes the state value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is the example of the problem.

**The situation I want**:-
Whenever the error occurs, error is saved the state, then `useEffect` sends the error in toast and then the error in state changes to null.

**The Problem faced**:-
With `useEffect` first I am getting the data and if error has occurred, then error is saved into the state and toast error occurs. After that error state is cleared and in the `useEffect` dependency array I have mentioned error also. So whenever the error occurs, `useEffect` is called.

But here the problem of infinite rendering occurs.
I have attached the code below for the reference.

ReducerFile.js

```js
const initialState = {
    product: {}
};

export const productSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'product detail',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        productDetailRequest: (state) => {
            state.loading = true;
            state.product = { ...state.product };

        },
        productDetailSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.product = action.payload;

        },
        productDetailFail: (state, action) => {
            state.error = action.payload;
            state.loading = false;
        },
        clearErrors: (state, action) => {
            state.error = null;
        }
    }
});
```

ActionFile.js

```js
export const getProductDetails = async (dispatch, id) => {
    try {
        dispatch(productDetailRequest());
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/details/${id}`);
        dispatch(productDetailSuccess(data.product));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        dispatch(productDetailFail(error.response.data.message));
    }
};

export const clearAllErrors = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(clearErrors());
};
```

component.js

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const { id } = useParams();
const { error, product, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetailReducer
);

useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
        toast.error(error);
        clearAllError(dispatch); // Here component re-renders whenever the error is changed
    }
    getProductDetails(dispatch, id);

}, [dispatch, id, error]);
```

In the case if error occur, `useEffect` triggers infinite rerenders.

How can render looping be avoided in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Use two `useEffect`s

```
useEffect(() => {
  getProductDetails(dispatch, id);
}, [dispatch, id]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (error) {
    toast.error(error);
    clearAllError(dispatch);
  }
}, [dispatch, error]);
```